# why we can't assign number to BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

We can store

```
Integer a= 12;
```

But we can't store like this

```
BigDecimal b =12;// what is the reason for that
```

Comment: Because there is no autoboxing conversion for the arbitrary precision types `BigDecimal` *or* `BigInteger`. The actual boxing conversions are [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

Answer (score 6):

BigDecimal is not a primitive. In order to have a BigDecimal you need to create an instance of it like `BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(12);`. From there you can call its various methods to do math with it, round it, etc.

With very, *very* few exceptions all Java Objects require that you assign the variable with an object of that type (or whatever follows the rules of polymorphism).